# How to add DesiredCapabilities to randomly pick any available browser in selenium grid2

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I have a grid2 setup with 7 nodes where each node has 1 instance of Firefox, chrome and IE.

When running the tests I don;t want to specify a particular browser. Instead, I would like the grid to pick a random available browser for my test.

Are there any DesiredCapabilities settings that I can use to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid uses one of the below three attributes in order to narrow down which node should a new session request be routed to :

1. Browser Name
2. Platform
3. Version

So one of these things is required for the test to be routed to a node.

There are two ways in which your need can be fulfilled by you :

1. You can build a utility locally in your test which when queried would give you back a random browser based DesiredCapability object (maybe on a round-robin basis) and thus achieve your use-case.
2. The other way of doing this is by building a custom capability matcher [ you can refer to [my blog post](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/working-with-a-custom-capability-matcher-in-the-grid/) for learning how to do this and wiring it into the grid ] and in this custom capability matcher, you build the logic of randomly picking a browser flavor and try updating the incoming requestedCapability map with that information. Your mileage here may vary because the map seems to be the original map that is fetched from the de-serialized JSON request that comes into the hub, so you could pull this off.

Personally I feel that option (1) is a lot more easy to manage and it can work with any Grid setup.

Updated section :
Going by what are looking for, here's the refinement you are looking for.

- (a) Build a servlet and inject it into the Grid hub. You can find instructions for doing that from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#customizing-the-grid).
- (b) In this newly built servlet, add logic which is around these lines

  ```
  org.openqa.grid.internal.Registry registry = null;
  List<RemoteProxy> freeProxies = new LinkedList<>();
  for (RemoteProxy eachProxy : registry.getAllProxies()) {
      if (eachProxy.isBusy()) {
          continue;
      }
      //Add logic here to extract out the next usable browser by querying
      //the Proxy's TestSlot

  }
  ```
- (c) Once you have injected this servlet into your Hub, then all you would be required to do is to make a call to this newly added servlet before exercising option (1) [ the utility that generates random desiredcapabilities object ], to find out which is the next usable browser flavor and then have your utility generate the capability accordingly.

PS : This solution would require you to work with a custom grid wherein you have added a custom servlet and hence can't work with plain vanilla grid setups.

Comment: option-1 is easy to maintain. But with that I could end up in a scenario where pending tests (lets say waiting for Firefox) even though I have instances available (lets say IE). If only there was a way to fetch info about available browser instances from grid.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the information that you are looking for, so that you can pursue option (1). But remember that this too shall require a custom grid and wont work with plain vanilla grids

Comment: Since both solutions customize the grid, I would rather go with the second solution. Thanks.